# Magento catalog price rules discount doesn't work with products with custom options

Tags: magento-1.7, cart, custom-options, catalog-price-rules

We have added several catalog price rules in our magento stores, but it seems that they don't get applied with additional costs that we set inside products with custom options, but they only work with standard product price, is there a way to fix this? thanks